# Getting LS means of the response from logistic regression in SAS

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model, sas

So, I know this is more of a programming question than a stats question, but I thought I might try here anyway.

I have a logistic regression model with a combination of categorical and continuous covariates, and I can calculate the least squares means of the transformed response for each treatment level in SAS using the `LSMEANS` statement in `PROC GENMOD`.  However, I can't seem to find any options to give me the back-transformed LS means of the response (i.e., the LS means of the probability and its associated CI), whereas it seems that in R, there is the option to do this in the `summary()` statement, with the `type = "response"` option.

I did see that in SAS, there's an `/ EXP` option that lets me exponentiate the LS mean to get an odds ratio, but am I just out of luck and forced to take this and manually calculate $\pi = OR/(1+OR)$?

Comment: So quick summary -- you don't want predicted probabilities for each person, but some group (treatment) wise predicted probabilities?

Comment: Yes, that's right.  Ideally, if I can get it both unweighted (i.e. balanced across the categorical variables) as well as weighted according to observed frequencies, that would be best.